# kml loading fails in different browsers - javascript / geoxml3 /google maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, cross-browser, kml

this code  works fine in Firefox, in chrome/internet explorer i get an error in console 'cannot open file' when trying to load the kml (generated from a php script)

since it works in FF, I don't think my code/kml has a problem, but maybe it requires an addition to make it work in other browsers? hmm... im not an expert, any advice to fix the code problem is welcome, 
many thanks!

using geoxml3 library / google maps apiv3

reference links:
usage of geoxml lib: http://erskinelabs.com/cartography-javascript/

Comment: So the problem seems to be in geoxml. I assume you don't want to use the KmlLayer option in the Google Maps API? One thing to check, what mime-type are you serving it out with?

Comment: when generating the kml i set Content-type: application/vnd.google-earth.kml+xml, i also dont want to use the kmllayer because when geoxml works it allows me to add a listener to the mouseover property on each marker which is not available in kmllayer

Comment: I'd suggest filing a bug on their issue tracker: http://code.google.com/p/geoxml3/issues/list it seems to be active.

Comment: I came accross an example of theirs on the website, http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/geoxml3_test_mtrmtrip_polygon_suppressInfoWindows.html which worked on all browsers, I then compared this code to mine and changed the way I passed the variables when calling the lib, to match the example here.  success! many thanks for sending me on the right direction!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with the GeoXML3 library is the way that Ajax request are handled in the geoXML3.fetchXML function, which is deprecated code and a bit dodgy. **If you are using jQuery** in you project, you just need to replace this function inside the geoxml3.js file with the following code:

```
geoXML3.fetchXML = function (url, callback) {
  function timeoutHandler() {
    callback();
  };
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: url,
    success: function(xml) {
        callback(xml);
    }
  });
};
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answer above you have to consider the 
1. different behaviour of IE in AJAX calls (cache) and 
2. you have to pass a DOM (Node) to the callback function; otherwise the  function
    will fail
3. another caveat with this approach in IE is, that there is a limit for strings  to convert it in XML DOM objects. That means there is size limit for KML files which can be loaded and rendered this way. I used this modification of  in geoxml3 to make ajax calls in IE work:

```
geoXML3.fetchXML = function (url, callback) {
  function timeoutHandler() {
     callback();
  };
$.ajax({
    type:       "GET",
    cache:      false,      
    url: url,
    success: function(xml) {
        var xmldom = createXMLDocument(xml);
        callback(xmldom);
    }
});
```

For converting a string to an XML DOM take a look here   http://www.w3schools.com/dom/dom_parser.asp

```
function createXMLDocument(strResponse)
{
   if (window.DOMParser)
   {
     parser=new DOMParser();
     xmlDoc=parser.parseFromString(strResponse,"text/xml");
   } else // Internet Explorer
   {
      xmlDoc=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
      xmlDoc.async=false;
     xmlDoc.loadXML(strResponse);
   } 
   return xmlDoc;
 }
```